# Convert a macro into a function call

Tags: c

I have a created a macro which will print the timestamp with all the prints.

```
void timestamp()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    printf("%d",tv.tv_sec );
}

#define printf_all(format, ...) {                           \
    static const char format_string[] = format; \
    printf(format_string, ##__VA_ARGS__);                  \
    timestamp(); \
}

int main()
{
    printf_all("%d\n",10);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to convert this macro into a function. But I am facing problems while passing in the arguments.

```
void printf_timestamp(static const char format_string[]) {                           
    static const char format_string[] = format; 
    printf(format_string, ##__VA_ARGS__);                  
    timestamp(); 
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to set format_string to anything since you declared it as a const. This should work if you remove that line, and pass the format as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Compiler is complaining about __VA_ARGS_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`vprintf`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf):

```
int printf_timestamp(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    int result;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    result = vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    timestamp();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You could also add this prototype 

    `int printf_all(const char *const format, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));`

to make `gcc` check the arguments as if it was a regular `printf()` function, of course in case you are using `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using the `vprintf()` function, as orlp explained. However, that alone leaves you with a format that cannot be typechecked: Usually, your compiler interpretes the format string literal in every `printf()` call that it sees to determine whether the corresponding arguments have the right types.

Some compilers allow you to add support for this kind of type checking, here is the `__attribute__(())` that is needed for `gcc`:

```
//within header
void printfTimestamp(const char* format, ...)
    __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

//within implementation file
void printfTimestamp(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int result = vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    timestamp();
    return result;
}
```

The arguments to the attribute are the argument number with the format string (`1`) and the first variable argument position (`2`). As such, if you were to add an additional parameter to your function, you would declare it like this:

```
void myPimpedPrintf(int foo, const char* format, ...)
    __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For just adding a timestamp, I agree that `vprintf()` as proposed by orlp is the way to go.  However, I think there is a valid argument in favor of macros, and that's the use of other compiler built-in macros like `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, and `__func__`, which I personally find very useful for logging.

I generally use something like this with `gcc` and anything else that does comma swallowing.

```
#define log_debug(M, ...) do{ \
  struct timespec _ts; \
  double _ts_sec; \
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &_ts);\
  _ts_sec = _ts.tv_nsec * 1e-9 + _ts.tv_sec; \
  fprintf(stderr, "%.3f [DEBUG] (%s:%d) " M,  _ts_sec, \
      __func__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
}while(0)

// usage:
log_debug("x=%d\n", x);
```

There are a couple "tricks" going on here you might not be familiar with.

The first of which is the `do{}while()` loop.  This is a fairly common and largely portable C idiom for writing multi-statement macros.  It lets you use the macro terminating it in a `;` and allows declaration of scoped variables.  However, is a statement, not an expression, so there's no "return value".  Usually doesn't matter for printf() like macros, but be aware, this can bite you in other uses when trying to make function-like macros.

The other "trick" is the use of comma swallowing with the '##' operator.  Read more here:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Also, this takes advantage of the fact that back-to-back string literals are concatenated in C to form a single string literal.  The downside is that this technique ONLY works with string literals, i.e. your format string cannot be in a variable.